# Firefox can not layout nested tables properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I want to implement a collapsible menu.  I plan to use table component to simulate a menu, and  nest a sub table into a table cell to simulate a sub menu.

Below is my code, it works as expected in IE, Chrome and Safari, but it doesn't work well in Firefox:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="menu" style="position:absolute; left:150px; top:100px; z-index:1">
  <table width="200px" height="90" border=1 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr> 
      <td colspan=2>Money</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan=2>Tool</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>Food
        <table style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:60px; z-index:1" width="200px" height="60px" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr> 
            <td>Cookie</td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>Fruit
              <table style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:30px; z-index:1" width="200px" height="60px" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr> 
                  <td>Apple</td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                  <td>Banana</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that Firefox think the "left" and "top" attribute for the level 3 menu is relative to the level 1 menu, so it layout the level 3 menu incorrectly.  Other browsers will calculate the offset base on the level 2 menu, that works as expected.

Is it a bug in Firefox?  If so how can I work around it?  I want my code to have the same behavior in all major browsers.

Comment: Oh boy. It's been a while that I've seen that many tables in one place :) :) Welcome to SO.

Comment: FWIW, I think you would have to give the `td`s `position: relative` for this to work but that will cause other problems. I think you should do this with a much, much simpler structure. I gotta go now but I'm sure somebody will come up with a suggestion.

Comment: @ooplidi, I have to agree with @Pekka - You will get some more issues if you use Relative, but this is also a better way to do it. Does this really HAVE to be in tables?

Comment: Again yes, Pekka is right - you need to have a container that has position: relative in order for the next position: absolute item to look at the container's coordinates.  Otherwise, all the position: absolute items may go up the tree to find the last position: relative container.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping tables in divs seems to solve the issue:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="menu" style="position:absolute; left:150px; top:100px; z-index:1">
  <table width="200px" height="90" border=1 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>Money</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>Tool</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Food
        <div style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:60px; z-index:1">
        <table width="200px" height="60px" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Cookie</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Fruit
              <div style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:30px; z-index:1;">
              <table  width="200px" height="60px" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>Apple</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Banana</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In fact it would be better not to use tables at all, but only divs with proper borders.

Comment: I second the "No Table" policy brough forward by @kgiannakakis ^_^

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. Tables should not be used for layouts.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895 .